# Is there a predefined class for 3 linked values like the Hashtable?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

Is there a built in object that handles 3 linked values in a similar fashion to the hashtable?  i.e. Key, Value1, Value2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have said generic dictionary too.

If you didn't want to do anything extensive, just make a struct or some sort of tuple out of Value1, Value2 and make those the value of your dictionary's Key. Something like:

```
Dictionary<Key, ThatTinyStructYouHadToCreate>
```

Bad idea:  If you didn't like that option, as far as "built-in" goes, a DataRow in a DataTable would give you that ability.  While that's a very simple way to set it up, it'd also be a remarkably inefficient (as far as execution cost) way to go about it.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, nice.

Answer (score 3):

You could easily make one using a generic dictionary.  Something like `Dictionary<Key, KeyValuePair<Key, Value>>`, or even `Dictionary<Key, object[]>`

Comment: I thought about that - this library wasn't supposed to be heavy duty though so I was hoping not to have to build/implement anything extensive.

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand.  Dictionary and KeyValuePair are already implemented in .NET.  You wouldnt have to build anything.

Comment: Oops - I guess your whole text didn't post before I was commenting... yes, I see what you're getting at.

Comment: I agree with Mike_G that this is probably the quickest way to implement what you want; but it probably won't yield the most maintainable code. In my experience, having a custom class as your "Value" with well named properties will be a lot clearer to people looking at your code for the first time.

Comment: Don't like the object[] route, but +1 for KeyValuePair. There's a non generic Pair class somewhere in the BCL that I also use occasionally, but all I recall is that it's somewhere in one of the Control namespaces (WebControl, Control, ComponentModel or something...)

Comment: Ya, object[] was just continue the example that the value in the dictionary could really be anything that can hold 2 values